# How to set wrap the text of Datatable based on specific character

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

my js file has `"bAutoWidth": false`

even after this whenever there is any text inside the column coming up more which has no spaces to wrap.
That time the table extends to right side of the page..

Client is not interested to see xScrool. can any one please assist me on this issue..?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Any jquery related settings also, please advise**

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS property for overflowing text. you can use following code

```
p{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:20px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

please note: above css is just an example. height widht may vary in your case, but the text-overflow: ellipsis should be used.